# Center a fixed div with unknown width

Tags: css, html, center, fixed

I have a div in body:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position: fixed">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

The `<img>` has its intrinsic width and height (and unknown). So how do I do to center the `<div>` in srceen (by CSS, not Jquery or Javascript)?

Comment: position: fixed can be omitted, did you try margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;?

Comment: Is the div the same size as the image otherwise your question doesn't make sense? Also, center vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Rc9fa/55/)**</kbd>

css

```
img {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the .wrapper to have a fixed position because you want to have it as a header or footer. This makes it wrap to its contents, so you need to explicitly tell it to stretch to 100% width. Next, img are displayed inline. Therefore, to use the auto margin trick, you need to set its display to block:

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
}
img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Working jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7swkv/